# i want to make generic parameters in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

How can I make generic parameters in jenkins that will be updated automatically for example I want to be able to create a parameter which hold today's date and it will be update automatically and not manually ?

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: where do you want to use the parameter? If you are doing bash scripting, you can use the (`)backticks to get the output of the unix date command.

Comment: I am trying to do it in the section "This build is parameterized" and adding a string parameter (20150628) I want to be able to set today's date for this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).

Setup your job and then add a build step "Inject envornment variables" from a file with an absolute path or the path relative to current job's workspace, which will contain something like:

```
DATE_VARIABLE="20150708"
OTHER_OPTIONAL_VARIABLE="value"
```

In previous execute shell step you may for example do:

```
echo "DATE_VARIABLE="`date +"%d%m%Y"` > env_inject.txt
```

After all that you don't need Parameters for a build, since you will have the needed parameter injected as an environment variable.

Comment: Thanks, 
what I am doing now is running a python script job via Jenkins I am using this command: 
python /home/py_version/single_run.py $threshold $date_start_time $date_end_time

while I configured date_end_time and date_start_time as "this build is parameterized" where i use this parameters as string parameters and I set default value which in order to be changed I have to update it manually.

I did not quite understood how can I use this EnvInject plugin in order to set generic value that will be updated automatically.

Can you elaborate more info?

Comment: Simply follow the steps I described in my answer if you want to use EnvInject. What happens is that you write current date to a file and then inject that file as a "variable=value" pair container to the build.

Comment: What language I use in the text file in order to use it in my script 

date = date.today() for example? which language I can use ?

Comment: You can use just about anything that will generate the following text in the file that will be used as environment injection input:

    TODAY_DATE="JULY-23"

The example:

echo "DATE_VARIABLE="`date +"%d%m%Y"` > env_inject.txt

is a Linux shell bash. But you may as well use anything else.